# append values/parameters to struct in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, block

I am trying to pass parameters to a struct in swift but this way of dealing with structs is a bit too far for me.

First of all, I am getting all values from a model that I have created. This model contains information that I can process. For example, my model contains productname, productdesc and product price etc.

I can get these values by putting a for loop and add all these value to a string or array. Then my code looks like as follows:

```
 var strString = ""
 var prodName = [] as [String]

 for i in 0 ..< self.orderModel.prod_arr.count
  {
      let model = orderModel.prod_arr[i]
      strString = strString + "\(model.prod_quantity!) " + "[\(model.prod_name!)] " + "(\(model.prod_price!))\n"
      prodName.append(model.prod_name!)
  }
```

On the other hand, I have a Receipt struct that only accepts types of blocks.

```
let tb = TextBlock("some variable or text") // this can not longer than 200 char

var receipt = Receipt(
    .title("Red Store"),
    .text(tb), //text type only accept TextBlocks

    for i in prodName{  //giving me error: Expected expression in list of expressions
    .title(i),
    }
        //SO how am i able to add the prodName array here if I cannot apply a for loop here?
        //strString also not working, even though I add ".text(" +variable+")" into the string

)
```

When I add the prodName into Receipt struct, it is showing me an error that Receipt can only accepts blocks. I did not made this struct so I don't know and I don't want to make changes to it.

So my question is, how can I append values/parameters to a struct or is this even possible?

Comment: `Receipt` in a library or where ?

Comment: https://github.com/KevinGong2013/Printer/blob/master/Printer/Blocks/Receipt.swift

Comment: It really depends what `Receipt` is and how it's setup. What is the exact error message you are getting on which line?

Comment: Expected expression in list of expressions at line below var receipt = Receipt( where I have for i in prodName{ .title(i) }

Comment: I don't understand the syntax.`var receipt = Receipt(
    .title("Red Store"),
    .text(tb),
    for i in prodName{  
    .title(i),
    }`, shouldn't it be something like `Receipt(title: "Red Store", text: tb)`?

Comment: no the syntax is ok, when I hardcode the values it works fine, I am stuck with struct giving my values from array...